# Twitter API - Get Tweets from a list of users

Tags: python, twitter, response, tweepy, keyerror

I am using the Twitter Academic Research V2 API and want to get tweets from a list of users and store them in a dataframe.
My code works for one single user, but not for a list of users. See the code here:

```
import tweepy
from twitter_authentication import bearer_token
import time
import pandas as pd
import time
client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

# list of twitter users
csu = ["Markus_Soeder", "DoroBaer", "andreasscheuer"]

csu_tweets = []
 
for politician in csu:
    for response in tweepy.Paginator(client.search_all_tweets, 
                                     query = f'from:{politician} -is:retweet lang:de',
                                     user_fields = ['username', 'public_metrics', 'description', 'location'],
                                     tweet_fields = ['created_at', 'geo', 'public_metrics', 'text'],
                                     expansions = 'author_id',
                                     start_time = '2022-12-01T00:00:00Z',
                                     end_time = '2022-12-03T00:00:00Z'):
        time.sleep(1)
        csu_tweets.append(response)

end = time.time()
print(f"Scraping of {csu} needed {(end - start)/60} minutes.")

result = []
user_dict = {}
# Loop through each response object
for response in csu_tweets:
    # Take all of the users, and put them into a dictionary of dictionaries with the info we want to keep
    for user in response.includes['users']:
        user_dict[user.id] = {'username': user.username, 
                              'followers': user.public_metrics['followers_count'],
                              'tweets': user.public_metrics['tweet_count'],
                              'description': user.description,
                              'location': user.location
                             }
    for tweet in response.data:
        # For each tweet, find the author's information
        author_info = user_dict[tweet.author_id]
        # Put all of the information we want to keep in a single dictionary for each tweet
        result.append({'author_id': tweet.author_id, 
                       'username': author_info['username'],
                       'author_followers': author_info['followers'],
                       'author_tweets': author_info['tweets'],
                       'author_description': author_info['description'],
                       'author_location': author_info['location'],
                       'text': tweet.text,
                       'created_at': tweet.created_at,
                       'quote_count': tweet.public_metrics['quote_count'],
                       'retweets': tweet.public_metrics['retweet_count'],
                       'replies': tweet.public_metrics['reply_count'],
                       'likes': tweet.public_metrics['like_count'],
                      })

# Change this list of dictionaries into a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(result)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_25716/2249018491.py in <module>
      4 for response in csu_tweets:
      5     # Take all of the users, and put them into a dictionary of dictionaries with the info we want to keep
----> 6     for user in response.includes['users']:
      7         user_dict[user.id] = {'username': user.username, 
      8                               'followers': user.public_metrics['followers_count'],

KeyError: 'users'
```

So I get this KeyError: 'users'. I don't get the error if I just scrape tweet from a single user and replace "csu = ["Markus_Soeder", "DoroBaer", "andreasscheuer"] with "csu = "Markus_Soeder".
Does anyone know what could be the issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this issue. It gave me the key error, because for some users in this time range there were no tweets and as a result it got stored as "none" in the response. Because of this the for loop didn't work.